# How can I scan for interference

Tags: rfi

What app or software can I use on my windows 10 computer(desktop) or iPhone 7 latest software to scan for interference as in another device effecting my frequencie of my Bluetooth wifi  in a 2.4 and 5 hz range.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but if you want to scan for "interference", then you most likely are not qualified to interpret scan results, even if you mange to actually get them. First step you need to take is to very clearly define what you actually mean by "interference" and explain that. Hopefully, we'll be able to tell you if that makes any sense or not. Also be careful. There's an entire industry dedicated to separating people, who have a vague idea that there's some "interference", and their money. So please be extra careful.

Comment: After this explanation, Kevin's answer and comments, and other comments: closing to vote this question as unclear, since OP passed several chances to clarify when explicitly asked to.

Comment: I agree with Marcus - this question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The radios built into computers are very special purpose, and they generally can only report RSSI or other information about signals in the *intended* mode (WiFi, Bluetooth, etc.) and not arbitrary RF energy.

Comment: What kind of radio would I need that would be best for doing this?

Comment: @LittleMac Could you edit your question to ask that?

Comment: I want to check for interference around my house, and I have a couple iPhones and a hp computer. I need to know if I can scan for interference

Comment: @LittleMac Please edit your question to say that; don't just leave a comment. Also, what kind of interference — interference with WiFi? Bluetooth? FM radio? et cetera.

Comment: @LittleMac   -- are you wanting to scan for interference, known as RFI for radio frequency interference which is caused by un-intentional generation of radio signals.   Or, are you wanting to scan for a jamming signal to see if someone is purposely jamming your cell phone signal?  Different methods and techniques are used depending on the type of interference.  Also note that in the US, there are stiff fines (~ $100,000) and prison time if caught purposely jamming cellular service.  Therefore, if you think you are being purposely jammed, contact your cellular carrier and they will test for you

Comment: I am still trying to figure out what type of frequencies they are. My Bluetooth wifi has been using up to 10gigs a day. It is on 2.4hz and 5.0 hz. And I've been through all the diagnostic test and my provider keeps saying there is interference. They won't say what it is so I would like to find out, I also live In an apartment so there are multiple electronic devices in the area ( if that has any effect). My question would be ," what kind of device can I use to scan thoes frequently

Comment: Sounds like your WiFi network might have been bootlegged by someone nearby.  Do you have all the best security protocols and methods in place to protect your network?  Also, you should be writing 2.4 GHz and 5.0 GHz instead of 2.4 Hz, etc.  Your question post could be considered a typo, your second mistake in the comment above looks like a misunderstanding.

Comment: @LittleMac - what is Bluetooth WiFi? Why do you think "using 10 gigs a day" would be connected to interference? I do not think searching for interference has anything to do with your issues.

Answer (score 1):

If by "desktop" you mean an ordinary PC, then you can get a (cheap) SDR dongle (see http://www.rtl-sdr.com/) and then you can use any of the SDR programs, preferably with waterfall display around suspected interference frequency. There are also some Android apps, I do not know about iPhone.

Comment: Note that RTL-SDRs don't go up to 2.4 GHz, let alone 5, so can't help with interference with e.g. WiFi.

Comment: But do they go down to 2.4 Hz?

Comment: @Phil_Frost I assume it's a typo, since 2.4 Hz is ridiculously low as a radio frequency. But anyway, typical cheap SDR dongles go down to tens MHz.

Answer (score 0):

I have used SDR# (read: Software Defined Radio Sharp) on a Windows 10 desktop to scan for signals, while doing so seeing how the noise floor changes dramatically. SDR# uses the waterfall display to help visualize noise, which would help one who isn't experienced in these sort of things be successful. In one case, I used SDR# to identify a noisy power supply that kept me from hearing a distant radio source.

The effectiveness of SDR# is related to the receiver you're using. While I was using an inexpensive TV tuner receiver, the range of the very cheap receivers are not created equally, so shop around.

While outside the scope of your question, I would like to add that the fun that can be had with SDR in general can be addictive. There are better receivers out there and an inexpensive raspberry pi project can also be built to accomplish the same thing if you need a more portable solution.